# Mysql search like google

Tags: php, mysql, search, match

I have a mysql table `tbl_users` which have `name` field.
This `name` field have following data.

```
1. Krishna
2. Tomas
3. Harry
```

I want to work it like this. When i search with the keyword `Thomas` it should match Tomas also. I tried with following query but it didn't work.

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_user` WHERE name like '%Thomas%'
```

I am not sure it is possible in `mysql` or not. Please suggest me how can i do this. I am using `php` with `mysql`.

Thanks

Comment: Read into the absolute basics of full-text search. "Similarity" is a whole world.

Comment: Don't you mean name and not username?

Comment: @KrishnaKarki Did you try that edited code?

Answer (score 4):

Try soundex, below is the example

```
select name from (
  select 'Thomas' as name
  union 
  select 'Tomas' as name
  union 
  select 'Ramprasad'  as name 
  )tmp
 where soundex(name)=soundex('Thomas')
```